# (CSS) Make element above all elements, regardless of size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a side-menu for my page.

[image: Current Result]

But, as you can see, the side menu's height pushes the elements after it downwards. The menu itself is sticky, which means when I scroll it scrolls above everything and nothing else is pushed down anymore.

[image: see here]

If I set the height of my element to `.1em` or something, nothing is pushed down anymore and the text is visible, however, then the borders are also becoming very small. I need the height to be auto in order for the borders to fully wrap the text.

How can I set the height to auto but without this pushing down the rest of the page? Like an element that is above everything and therefore doesn't affect the other stuff on z-index: 0.

This is what I have tried:

```
.sideMenu {
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 2px solid #73AD21;
    padding: .5em;
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-left: 1em;
    top: 10em;
    max-width: 15%;
    height: auto; 
    /*overflow-y: scroll;*/
    z-index: 100;
    position:sticky;
}
```

Comment: So the second image is what you want, then?

Comment: Well yes, but this only happens AFTER i scroll, i want the menu to be next to the title "who we are". but it pushes it down before it scrolls :)

Comment: just writing your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually have two solutions.

### Solution one

`position: sticky` basically makes it so that when you scroll down, it stays in the same place, but it still takes up the space where it previously was. To stop this happening, you can use `position: fixed`, which does not do this.

```css
.sideMenu{ 
    border-radius: 25px; 
    border: 2px solid #73AD21; 
    padding: .5em; 
    margin-top: 3em; 
    margin-left: 1em; 
    top: 10em; 
    max-width: 15%; 
    height: auto; 
    /* overflow-y: scroll;*/ 
    z-index: 100; 
    position: fixed; 
}
```

---

### Solution two

The problem with solution one is that it does not work when you scroll to a place which is higher than the sidebar. So you can keep `position: sticky`, but do some more modifications to the positioning, like `float: left`. I suppose you could also use flexbox. And this should make them go side by side!

```css
.sideMenu{ 
    border-radius: 25px; 
    border: 2px solid #73AD21; 
    padding: .5em; 
    margin-top: 3em; 
    margin-left: 1em; 
    top: 10em; 
    max-width: 15%; 
    height: auto; 
    /* overflow-y: scroll;*/ 
    z-index: 100; 
    position: sticky;
    float: left;
}
.content {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: AWESOME! Both solution worked fine, but the second one left the starting position where it was while the first solution pushed the object to the beginning of everything. So solution 2 is really splendid! Thank you so much! (Also I did vote, but I am not worthy enough yet ;-))